# How to fix Segmentation fault in a command line argument

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create a cipher coder in C, so far I have the following code. The if statement doesn't work properly and pops up segmentation fault whenever something is inputted whether it be a digit or just a letter. The else statement which is supposed to print out how to use the cipher text only prints it out when there is a space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[]) //im certain the problem is on this line but I dont know where exactly nor do I know how to fix it
{
    if (isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        string s = get_string("Cipher Text: ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
}
```

I'm certain the error has to deal with the string in the command line argument but I'm not to sure on what steps to take to fix it.

Comment: use https://getpot.sourceforge.net

Comment: Please enable full compiler warnings which should flag `isdigit(argv[1])` for passing the wrong type. CS50 isn't doing you any favours with its homebrew type `string` which causes more problems than it solves. Also please *always* check `argc` before accessing `argv`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very small program to show how you can access arguments of a C program.

It only uses standard C features (not CS50 or special string type).

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    int i;

    printf("argc=%d\n", argc);

    for (i=0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from `stdio.h`, what are the other includes for?

Comment: You are right: they are not needed. I have removed them.